# URL Data Binding in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, attachment, url, databinding

I have attachment Id and I need the URL for that particular attachment.

But In my LWC component I am constructing the URL programmatically like:

I want to avoid hardcoding the first part of the string /servlet/servlet.FileDownload.. Is there anything similar in LWC that we can use to get the URL directly

Comment: Can you add relevant code?

Comment: Are you talking about org instance URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the NavigationMixin in LWC -

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_open_files